# The python code I made is very slow. Is there a suitable way to optimize for this?

Tags: python

I have a question because the execution time of my Python code is taking too long.

This code reads from 1 to 30 files, collects and outputs the data in them, and each file has about 150,000 lines.

The program made by my boss in perl runs about 1 minute faster than the program I made.

When I run a program that reads 30 files, it takes about 1 minute and 30 seconds.

What parts should I do in this code?

thank you

Here is my code.

How can I more faster than this code?

I am very noob of python.

Please help me.

Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import sys
import shutil
import time
import pwd
import grp
import os
import re
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
def check_info(filename):
    counts = {}
    system="maru"
    node_pattern = rf"{system}.*?\d+"
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as FILE:
        for i in FILE:
            if "RUN" in i:
                nodes = []
                job_line = i.split()
                user = job_line[3]
                job = job_line[2]
                for part in i.split(":"):
                    nodes.extend(re.findall(node_pattern, part))
                    # findall is used to find all instances of a regular expression pattern in a string and return them as a list of matching substrings.

                if (user, job) in counts:
                    counts[(user, job)]["count"] += 1 ## job count

                else:
                    counts[(user, job)] = {"count": 1, "nodes": nodes}

            else:
                continue

#        way to print dictionary
#        counts_p = counts['k-da-at03', '595970']
#        print(counts_p["count"], counts_p["nodes"])
    username = []
    for key in counts.keys():
        username.append(key[0])

    username = list(set(username))

    user_duration = {}
    for user, job in counts:
        node_counts = len(counts[(user, job)]["nodes"])
        duration = round((node_counts * counts[(user, job)]["count"]) / 1400, 2)
        if user in user_duration:
            user_duration[user] += duration
        else:
            user_duration[user] = duration

    sorted_users = sorted(user_duration.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return(user_duration, username)


def USAGE():
    print("usage: ./l_monthly_sys_user_usage_for_compute.py")
    return

def main(): #### main
    DIR="/root/haechan"
    FILE="bjobs"

    argument = sys.argv
    if len(argument) == 1:
        pass

    elif len(argument) == 2:
        if argument[1] == "-h" or argument[1] == "--help":
            USAGE()
            return

        else:
            USAGE()
            os._exit(1)

    else:
        USAGE()
        os._exit(1)

    _DATE_ = input("Input date: {START DAY} {END DAY}\nInput date: 230101 230131\ndate: ")
    print()

    try:
        if len(_DATE_.split()) == 1:
            date1 = datetime.strptime(_DATE_.split()[0], "%y%m%d")
            date2 = datetime.strptime(_DATE_.split()[0], "%y%m%d")
        elif len(_DATE_.split()) == 2:
            date1 = datetime.strptime(_DATE_.split()[0], "%y%m%d")
            date2 = datetime.strptime(_DATE_.split()[1], "%y%m%d")
        else:
            print("Invalid Date")
            os._exit(1)
    except:
        USAGE()
        os._exit(1)

    delta = date2 - date1
    delta = range(delta.days + 1)
    delta_len = len(delta)
    cnt = 0
    value = {}
    date_list = []

    for A in delta:
        date = date1 + timedelta(days=A)
        date = date.strftime('%y%m%d')
        date_list.append(date)
        filename = f'{DIR}/{FILE}.{date}'

#        sorted_users = check_info(filename)
        user_duration,usernames = check_info(filename)

        if delta_len == 1:
            print("{:<15} {}".format("Username", *date_list))
            for user, duration in user_duration.items():
                print("{:<15} {}".format(user, round(duration, 2)))
            return

        elif delta_len > 1:
            for username in usernames:
                if username in user_duration:
                    if username in value:
                        value[username].append(round(user_duration[username],2))
                    else:
                        if cnt == 0:
                            value[username] = [round(user_duration[username],2)]
                        else:
                            value[username] = [0] * cnt + [round(user_duration[username], 2)]
                else:
                    value[username] = [0] * cnt

                if len(value[username]) < cnt:
                    value[username].append(0)

        cnt += 1
    u_val = ""
    u_date = ""
    for day in date_list:
        u_date = u_date + "{:<8}".format(day)
    print("{:<15} {}".format("User", u_date))
    for user in usernames:
        for val in value[user]:
            val = str(val)
            u_val = (u_val + "{:<8}".format(val))
        print("{:<15} {}".format(user, u_val))
        u_val = ""


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This probably belongs more on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You would first need to measure where it's spending its time with a profiler, then fix the hot parts.

Comment: Have you considered multithreading or multiprocessing?

Comment: Don't know how much it will help, but you can try compiling the regexp: `node_pattern = re.compile(rf"{system}.*?\d+")`

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. All the argument processing is irrelevant to the performance problem when processing the file.

Comment: What's the point of creating `sorted_users` if you never use it?

Comment: Is the algorithm the same in your boss's version? If not, it could just be better optimizations in perl for text processing like this. This is the kind of application it was designed for.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for your comment. I realize that 'sorted_users' should be deleted, but I forgot to do so. Also, the algorithms between my code and the Perl code are not the same. It's difficult for me to fully understand and analyze the Perl code. In general, I thought that Python was faster than Perl when processing files, but it seems like that's not the case. And thank you for showing me how to compile regular expressions.

Comment: @DarkKnight
As you can see from the level of the code, I haven't reached that level yet...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `check_info` is the slowest part, this is how you could rewrite it.

```
from collections import Counter
def check_info(filename):
    duration = Counter()    # use a counter for convenience
    nodes = {}
    system="maru"
    node_pattern = re.compile(rf"{system}.*?\d+")   # compile the regex in advance
    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for line in file:
            if "RUN" in line:
                job, user = line.split()[2:4]
                if (user, job) in nodes:
                    job_nodes = nodes[(user, job)]
                else:
                    # only apply the regex if the node for this (user, job) is not found
                    job_nodes = sum(len(node_pattern.findall(part))
                                    for part in line.split(":"))  
                    nodes[(user, job)] = job_nodes

                # all we need is the total duration for each user (nodes * count / 1400), so no need to store all the nodes information, or a separate count
                duration[user] += job_nodes
    
    # at the final stage divide by 1400; probably no need to round (that can be done using formatted string when printing)
    # There is no need to return a separate list of user names - they are just the keys of the duration Counter
    return {k: v / 1400 for k, v in duration.items()}
```

Your loops and checks in `main` can also be simplified.

```
def main():
    ...
    values = {}
    dates = []
    for day in range((date2 - date1).days + 1):
        date = (date1 + timedelta(days=day)).strftime('%y%m%d')
        dates.append(date)
        filename = f'{DIR}/{FILE}.{date}'
        user_duration = check_info(filename)
        for user, duration in user_duration.items():   # no need to check username and user_duration separately
            if user in values:
                values[user].append(duration) # no need to round here - do that when printing
            else:
                values[user] = [0] * day + [duration]
        # Add a 0 to any found users found previously but not in the current file
        for user in set(values) - set(user_duration):
            values[user].append(0)
    
    u_date = "".join(f"{date:<8}" for date in dates)
    print(f"{'User':<15} {u_date}")
    for user, value in values.items():  # all of the users will be in `values` so no need to check `usernames`
        u_val = "".join(f"{val:<8.2f}" for val in values)
        print(f"{user:<15} {u_val}")
```

Or use a `defaultdict` to simplify and make the main loop more efficient.

```
import collections
...
def main():
    ...
    days = (date2 - date1).days + 1
    values = collections.defaultdict(lambda: [0] * days)
    dates = []
    for day in range(days):
        date = (date1 + timedelta(days=day)).strftime('%y%m%d')
        dates.append(date)
        filename = f'{DIR}/{FILE}.{date}'
        user_duration = check_info(filename)
        for user, duration in user_duration.items():   # no need to check username and user_duration separately
            values[user][day] = duration
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I can't return the result of check_info function. error message is next.:
too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: see edit - the last line of `check_info` should be `return {k: v / 1400 for k, v in duration.items()}`